# How to post JSON data to SQL using ajax post & knockout

Tags: asp.net, json, knockout.js

I have a pretty straightforward view model:

```
 var ProjectViewModel = {
        ProjectName: ko.observable().extend({ required: "" }),
        ProjectDescription: ko.observable().extend({ required: "" }),
        ProjectStartDate: ko.observable(),
        ProjectEndDate: ko.observable()
    };
```

I want to save this data that is located in my viewmodel to my SQL server.
I have a class defining this View Model in my Server Side Code:

```
 public class Projects
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectEndDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

}
```

I also have this web method to receive the code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public bool SaveProject(string[] JSONDATA)
    {
        TaskNinjaEntities entities = new TaskNinjaEntities();

        foreach (var item in JSONDATA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
        }

        return true;      

    }
```

And finally I have this POST that does not want to send the data to the server:

```
function SaveMe() {

        var data = ko.toJSON(ProjectViewModel);
        $.post("CreateProject.aspx/SaveProject", data, function (returnedData) {
        });
    }
```

I get nothing from the returned data in this post method, also added breakpoint in server side code, and it doesn't hit it at all. My URL is correct and the Viewmodel converts to JSON without hassle.

Comment: Have you looked at what the POST looks like in the Network tab of your web developer tools or Fiddler?

Comment: +1 For using Fiddler to find out what's going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Make the web method static.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool SaveProject(string[] JSONDATA)
{
    TaskNinjaEntities entities = new TaskNinjaEntities();

    foreach (var item in JSONDATA)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
    }

    return true;         

}
```